# CiviDiscount's entry field is not appearing

Tags: cividiscount

I had a discount code set up for our event to facilitate complimentary registrations.  The box that used to appear at the top is no longer there.  Not sure what happened to it.

Comment: Is the CiviDiscount extension still enabled?

Comment: Hi Linda welcome to CiviCRM SE. Check status of all extensions, and as Aidan says 'are you sure it is plugged in and turned on', also what happens if you create a new Discount code etc etc. Better answers will comeforth when you are able to provide some more info that might help others interpret what is happening